# Interpretation of qPCR results for low expression genes

Tags: bioinformatics, gene-expression, lab-techniques, pcr

I am attempting to validate existence of a transcript using 40 cycle qPCR. I designed primers for a unique feature of this transcript, and also designed primers for a sequence in the transcript that is common to several transcripts of this gene, and finally I used GAPDH as a control. I already knew beforehand that this transcript has very low expression.

For the unique region, my ct values for primer 1 were between 31-34.8, and my ct values for primer2 and primer 3 were all consistently 35, and primers 4-6 gave no result at all.

For the region that is common to several transcripts of this gene, the ct values were between 30-34 for one primer, and consistently 35 for another primer.

For GAPDH, ct values were around 22.

Can I use these results to indicate that my transcript exists (or even may exist?) in the samples I tested? Is the fact that the ct values for the region unique to the transcript I am targeting and the region in common between several transcripts are quite close indicative of anything? On the graph from the qPCR, there are distinct rises respectively around 33 and 35 for the unique region amplicon.

EDIT: I was doing a bit more research, and it appeared that this study: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4296690/
also had results that came up "late cp call last five cycles has higher uncertainty" and considered these results positive if they could be replicated in a duplicate - if I were to show this as well, can I use this data in a paper?

Comment: What have you done to validate the conditions of your reverse-transcription and real-time PCR with respect to these transcripts? Can you get more input mRNA (say, enough so that $C_t$ values for GAPDH are well under 20)? Is the final PCR product for your transcript-specific primers at least the correct size based on your predicted transcript? Note that $C_t$ values differing by 4 units represent 16-fold differences in transcript abundance.

Comment: @EdM Well the mRNA was converted to cDNA quite a long time ago, and I simply ran a qpcr on the cDNA- the transcript I am trying to validate is a novel predicted one, so I guess I have not done anything to validate the conditions of the reaction specific to this transcript. The concentration of cDNA I used was 100 nanograms / microliter, so I guess I could try to increase the cDNA amount. How would I know if my product is the correct size from a qPCR? I am planning on establishing a concentration curve next Monday for the primer that seemed to work the best.

Comment: @pMarkov you validate PCR product size by running regular old-fashioned PCR with your primer pair of interest, and run the reaction out on a gel with a ladder for reference.

Comment: @MattDMo, ah silly me, thank you, I'll be sure to do that as soon as possible.

Comment: If you can't replicate the biological experiment, all the re-analysis of old cDNA isn't going to be good enough. Reproduce the conditions that led to the hypothesized production of the novel transcript, at a scale that allows better control of PCR conditions.

Comment: No prob. Sometimes we get too caught up in all the technology in the lab and forget about the simple stuff...

Comment: @EdM- could you elaborate a bit on the scale that would give me greater control on the PCR conditions? What types of parameters could I look into altering? The cDNA I am using is derived from the same phenotype that produced this "novel" transcript- I'm trying to validate existence of the transcript (/if primers work) in this abundant cDNA before I proceed to the more precious cDNA from samples I originally detected the transcript in. I was wondering if the results above were indicative enough to proceed testing, or what I could do/parameters to change to get stronger results before I move on

Comment: Transcripts from the same gene, and the gene itself, are notorious for low expression- I truly appreciate the advice/help!

Comment: To validate the existence of transcripts could be done by sequencing of PCR products amplified if you can deny contamination and amplification from genomic DNA.

Comment: When you have one copy of your target cDNA in a PCR tube, theoretically  Ct would be 34 around in an ideal condition: the PCR efficiency is 100%. You might want to check the efficiency of these primer sets.

Comment: @243- I'm guessing I would have to clean the qPCR product before I submit it for sequencing?- Usually we design a completely new set of primers from a different software for sequencing. I have not checked primer efficiency- good idea, another test to run next week. Can anyone speak to what (if any) conclusions may be drawn from the results above?

Comment: @pMarkov as MattDMo said, do a conventional PCR. Also do a 3'/5' RACE to confirm the actual size.